# How To Pause and Continue Windows Service By C#

Tags: c#, windows-services

i write a windows service by c# 4 and override some methods for it, like OnStart() and OnStop() and OnPause() and OnContinue() and OnShutdown().

i can start or stop this windows service, but i can not pause or continue it whether by programming or in services.msc. in other words, Start and Stop are Enable and Pause and Resume Options is Disable.

[image]

what is problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to set the [`CanPauseAndContinue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.canpauseandcontinue.aspx) property to true as well. This is documented in [`OnContinue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.oncontinue.aspx):

> OnContinue is expected to be overridden when the CanPauseAndContinue property is true.
>
> If CanPauseAndContinue is false, the SCM will not pass Pause or Continue requests to the service, so the OnPause and OnContinue methods will not be called even if they are implemented. In the SCM, the Pause and Continue controls are disabled when CanPauseAndContinue is false.